# How to reasign indentation after converting all paragraphs to a table in Word document with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm regularly working with large Word documents. I have to convert all  paragraphs to a table.

Source document structure sample:

[image]

After conversion (Insert -> Table -> Convert text to table) Word loses information about indents for random paragraphs. Target document:

[image]

As you can see, indents for paragraphs "c" and "d" disappeared. Don't know why but it happens quite often.

It should be exactly the same as in the source documents:

[image]

Finding and correcting the errors for very large documents takes hours, so I thought that I can repair broken indents in the target document by taking indent values from the source paragraphs.

This is my first attempt using VBA, I started like this:

```
Dim sourceDocument, targetDocument As Document
Dim myRange As Range
Set sourceDocument = ActiveDocument
Set targetDocument = Documents.Add(ActiveDocument.FullName)
Set myRange = targetDocument.Range(Start:=targetDocument.paragraphs(1).Range.Start, End:=targetDocument.paragraphs(targetDocument.paragraphs.Count).Range.End)
myRange.converttotable Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To targetDocument.Tables(1).Range.Rows.Count
    targetDocument.Tables(1).Range.Rows(i).Range.Cells(1).Range.paragraphs(1).LeftIndent = sourceDocument.paragraphs(i).LeftIndent
    targetDocument.Tables(1).Range.Rows(i).Range.Cells(1).Range.paragraphs(1).FirstLineIndent = sourceDocument.paragraphs(i).FirstLineIndent
Next i
```

The script works as expected for simple paragraphs since the number of paragraphs matches the count of rows in the target table. But in the case of tables existing in source document it gets messy. In tables, the number of paragraphs is doubled.

Source tables are nested in one target cell which is fine, no problems with them, and they do not have to be corrected.

So my question is how to match source paragraphs with target paragraphs in tables (omitting source tables and target nested tables)?

Or maybe there is another way of converting paragraphs to a table with correct indentation?

Comment: Ok, updated with screenshots. All paragraphs have different indentation and there is a lots of them. Formating of the source material is not an option. My job is to only convert text to table and keep formatting according to source material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be a number of ways to approach this. After some consideration, I decided a fairly straight-forward one would be to get an array of all the paragraphs *not* in a table from the source document.

When looping the rows in the target document the number of paragraphs will be greater than one only in rows that contain a nested table. In this case, the `Range` is set to the end (last paragraph).

Then the indent is applied from the corresponding paragraph in the array using the loop counter (plus 1, since arrays are 0-based).

```
Sub RestoreParaIndents()
    Dim sourceDocument As Document, targetDocument As Document
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set sourceDocument = ActiveDocument
    Set targetDocument = Documents.Add(ActiveDocument.FullName)
    Set myRange = targetDocument.content  

    'Get an array of all paragraphs not in a table in the source document
    'This will provide the indent information in the loop for the target document
    Dim aParas() As Paragraph, para As Paragraph
    Dim counterPara As Long
    counterPara = 0
    For Each para In sourceDocument.Paragraphs
        If Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            ReDim Preserve aParas(counterPara)
            Set aParas(counterPara) = para
            counterPara = counterPara + 1
        End If
    Next

    myRange.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rw As Row, rng As Range
    For i = 1 To targetDocument.Tables(1).Range.Rows.Count
        Set rw = targetDocument.Tables(1).Range.Rows(i)
        Set rng = rw.Range.Cells(1).Range

        'If the cell contains multiple paragraphs then in contains
        'a nested table. Skip the table and go to the end (last paragraph)
        If rng.Paragraphs.Count > 1 Then
            Set rng = rng.Paragraphs.Last.Range
        End If
        rng.Paragraphs(1).LeftIndent = aParas(i - 1).LeftIndent
        rng.Paragraphs(1).FirstLineIndent = aParas(i - 1).FirstLineIndent 
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :) Is there any chance to additionally detect and skip all paragraphs that belongs to Table of Contents? If not, it can be as is :)

Comment: I solved this additional issue by simply removing all TOC instances from the source document before collecting the source paragraphs. Target TOC contains multiple paragraphs and is omitted like nested tables.